# Javascript: select.options doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code, to iterate through the Options of a Select and mark the option with value 1 as selected, but it doesn't work properly, giving me the error

> "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

What's the problem here? Might be of importance: If i use `$('#Select').length` it works, however, all tutorials i've found work the other way, and i have no idea how to access the options any other way.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#Select').options.length; i++) {
    if ($(this).options[i].value == 1)
        $(this).selectedIndex = i;
}
```

Comment: What is `$`? jQuery or another library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here.

First you can't write `$('#Select').options.length`, which has no sense. To get the number of `<option>` elements in the `#Select` (which is likely a `<select>` element), you can do `$('#Select option').length`.

Anyway since you want to

> mark the option with value 1 as selected

you don't need to iterate and can simply use:

```
$('#Select option[value=1]').attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Select option[value="1"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: my major problem is getting the if-clause to work. i can't even know if the selecting works, because my error occurs when matching the value with the value id like to select. How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete example of your data and what you would like to do with it? Maybe that would help a bit.

Comment: Nevermind i have read your answer wrong. i thought you wanted me to use this line in my if-clause, and not as a standalone. sry for the misunderstanding. your solution worked though :)

Comment: Cheers mate. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use native Dom attributes with jQuery objects. here is a way to do the same with just javascript.

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#select');

selectByValue( select, '1' );

function selectByValue( select, value ){
  // use array prototype to filter down to a single value
  var option = Array.prototype.filter.call( select, function( option ){
    option.removeAttribute('selected');
    return option.value == value;
  })
  console.log( option[0] );
  // if there is an option that matches set it's selected attribute
  option[0] && option[0].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="0" id="option_zero">zero</option>
  <option value="1" id="option_one">one</option>
  <option value="2" id="option_two">two</option>
</select>
```